# problem with frames in html

Tags: html

i have a page which is divided into frames..and in one of the frame i have a hyperlink which when clicked must open another page in the same window. But it opens the new page in the frame itself. How do i open another page in the whole window rather than in the frame itself

Comment: How are you doing it? Give some snippet, otherwise there is no way for us to see what is wrong? BTW, frames are pretty outdated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure the link `target` attribute is set to `_top`.

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_top">Link to open in whole window</a>
```

Read about the different values this attribute can take and how they behave [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#adef-target) is the relevant section of the HTML 4.01 spec.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a target: `<a href="..." target="_top">`

Read here: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET.html

Answer (score 0):

Add target="_top" as an attribute to your hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Use a target of '_top' : e.g:

```
<a href="mylink.html" target="_top">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click your hyperlink you need to give it a parameter such as

```
<a href="yoursite.com?page=about-us"></a>
```

Then in the $_POST variable of php you can access your variable using $_POST['page'] which you can use to determine which page you wish to include for your main contact frame. Therefore only one frame changes on your site.

By the way frames are frowned upon these days. Have a look at MVC ( model view controller )

Comment: What has the page parameter got to do with the OP's question?